# Not able to display images from an external website in a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-image

I try to display the full content of a web page into a `WebView`. The text is displayed correctly but the images not. I've searched tons of posts but none of them helped me. This is what I have tried:

```
webView = myFragment.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
webView.loadUrl(URL);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + description);

    }
});
```

The `URL` that I'm passing to the `loadUrl()` function looks like this:

```
mydomain.com/category/category_name/
```

I have also tried:

```
mydomain.com/category/category_name/index.php
```

But it doesn't display the images, only the text. How to solve ths?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: what is app target level ?

Comment: @HemantParmar `minSdkVersion 21` and `compileSdkVersion 28` and `targetSdkVersion 28`

Comment: while hit url on browser , is that working ?

Comment: @HemantParmar Yes, it's working perfect.

Comment: try to enable java script and `vistaWeb.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient(this));` add this too.

Comment: @HemantParmar I did and the I have the same behaviour. For future visitor, `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webSettings.setBlockNetworkImage(false);
```